tcolorbox for latex code with texlive 2023
I'm sorry for my MWE too big. However I don't know how to make it smaller in this case.
I want to use tcolorbox to frame latex code. Unless I'm mistaken this code worked under the texlive 2017 distribution. Now with Ubuntu 24.04LTS and texlive 2023 I have a slight typo that appears.
here is the first mwe to make a box with title
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{coltria/.style={fill=red!15!white}}

%-------------------------
%   box dédiée au code latex avec titre
%-------------------------
\newtcblisting{latex}[2][]
{empty,breakable,leftrule=5mm,left=2mm,
    frame style={fill,top color=green!75!black,bottom color=green!75!black,middle color=green},
    listing only,
    listing engine=listings,
    %       listing options={style=latexliststyle,tabsize=4,breaklines,
        listing options={tabsize=4,breaklines,
            breakindent=1.5em,columns=fullflexible},
        colback=yellow!15!white,
        %-------------------------
        % code for unbroken boxes:
        %-------------------------
        frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
            --([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
            --([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle; },
        interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west)--(interior.north west)
            --([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)--([yshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)
            --([yshift=4.8mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.south east)
            --cycle; },
        attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
        title=\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\red{#2}},
        %-------------------------
        % code for the first part of a break sequence:
        %-------------------------
        skin first is subskin of={emptyfirst}{%
            frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
                --([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
                --(frame.south east)--cycle;
                \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=1mm]frame.south west) -- +(120:2mm)
                -- +(60:2mm)-- cycle; },
            interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west|-frame.south)
                --(interior.north west)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)
                --([yshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)--(interior.south east|-frame.south)
                --cycle; },
        },
        %-------------------------
        % code for the middle part of a break sequence:
        %-------------------------
        skin middle is subskin of={emptymiddle}{%
            frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
                --(frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--cycle;
                \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) -- +(240:2mm)
                -- +(300:2mm) -- cycle;
                \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=1mm]frame.south west) -- +(120:2mm)
                -- +(60:2mm) -- cycle;
            },
            interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west|-frame.south)
                --(interior.north west|-frame.north)--(interior.north east|-frame.north)
                --(interior.south east|-frame.south)--cycle; },
        },
        %-------------------------
        % code for the last part of a break sequence:
        %-------------------------
        skin last is subskin of={emptylast}{%
            frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
                --(frame.north east)--([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)
                --([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle;
                \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) -- +(240:2mm)
                -- +(300:2mm) -- cycle;
            },
            interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west)
                --(interior.north west|-frame.north)--(interior.north east|-frame.north)
                --([yshift=4.8mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.south east)
                --cycle; }, #1}}
        
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{latex}{exemple latex}
        \section{Installation sur système Linux}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength\itemsep{0.05em} %semble ok 
            \item Pour l'installation minimale, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive}}
            
            \item Pour le support de la langue française, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-lang-french};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-lang-french}}
            
            \item Pour une compilation de greffons bien utiles, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-latex-extra};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-latex-extra}}
            \item \green{Pour l'installation complète sans se poser de question au sujet des paquets supplémentaires, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-full}
                \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-full}}
                \footnote{Lua\LaTeX, une variante de \LaTeX{} utilisant le langage de script Lua est également installée. je vous le recommande}}.
        \end{itemize}
        
        \subsection{Installation optimale pour Ubuntu}
    \end{latex}
    

\end{document}

here there is only one error that appears
here it is
97: Undefined control sequence. \end{latex}

here is the 2nd mwe to make a box this time without title
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{coltria/.style={fill=red!15!white}}

    %-------------------------      
    %   box dédiée au code latex sans titre
    %-------------------------
    \newtcblisting{latex*}[1][]
    {empty,breakable,leftrule=5mm,left=2mm,
        frame style={fill,top color=green!75!black,bottom color=green!75!black,middle color=green},
        listing only,
        listing engine=listings,
        %listing options={style=latexlst,tabsize=4,breaklines,
            listing options={tabsize=4,breaklines,
                breakindent=1.5em,columns=fullflexible},
            %       keywordstyle=\color{red}},
        colback=yellow!15!white,
        %   watermark color=red!50!yellow!75!white,
        %   watermark text on=unbroken is unbroken box,
        %   watermark text on=first is first part,
        %   watermark text on=middle is middle part,
        %   watermark text on=last is last part,
        %-------------------------
        % code for unbroken boxes:
        %-------------------------      
        frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
            --([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
            --([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle; },
        interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west)--(interior.north west)
            --([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)--([yshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)
            --([yshift=4.8mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.south east)
            --cycle; },
        attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
        %-------------------------
        % code for the first part of a break sequence:
        %-------------------------
        skin first is subskin of={emptyfirst}{%
            frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
                --([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
                --(frame.south east)--cycle;
                \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=1mm]frame.south west) -- +(120:2mm)
                -- +(60:2mm)-- cycle; },
            interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west|-frame.south)
                --(interior.north west)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)
                --([yshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)--(interior.south east|-frame.south)
                --cycle; },
        },
        %-------------------------
        % code for the middle part of a break sequence:
        %-------------------------
        skin middle is subskin of={emptymiddle}{%
            frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
                --(frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--cycle;
                \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) -- +(240:2mm)
                -- +(300:2mm) -- cycle;
                \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=1mm]frame.south west) -- +(120:2mm)
                -- +(60:2mm) -- cycle;
            },
            interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west|-frame.south)
                --(interior.north west|-frame.north)--(interior.north east|-frame.north)
                --(interior.south east|-frame.south)--cycle; },
        },
        %-------------------------
        % code for the last part of a break sequence:
        %-------------------------
        skin last is subskin of={emptylast}{%
            frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
                --(frame.north east)--([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)
                --([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle;
                \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) -- +(240:2mm)
                -- +(300:2mm) -- cycle;
            },
            interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west)
                --(interior.north west|-frame.north)--(interior.north east|-frame.north)
                --([yshift=4.8mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.south east)
                --cycle; }, #1}}    
    
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{latex*}
        \section{Installation sur système Linux}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength\itemsep{0.05em} %semble ok 
            \item Pour l'installation minimale, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive}}
            
            \item Pour le support de la langue française, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-lang-french};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-lang-french}}
            
            \item Pour une compilation de greffons bien utiles, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-latex-extra};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-latex-extra}}
            \item \green{Pour l'installation complète sans se poser de question au sujet des paquets supplémentaires, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-full}
                \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-full}}
                \footnote{Lua\LaTeX, une variante de \LaTeX{} utilisant le langage de script Lua est également installée. je vous le recommande}}.
        \end{itemize}
        
        \subsection{Installation optimale pour Ubuntu}
    \end{latex*}
\end{document}

this time the beginning of the text inside the box is eaten the word section is missing.
Can you enlighten me on these 2 anomalies? I'm almost there, because it produces almost my 2 boxes.
note: I am forced to compile in lualatex in my project for other reasons external to my question
could you help me to understand what is about?

To begin with, \red is undefined and produces an error also with TL 2017. If I define it by
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

the file compiles, but you lose all accented characters. With TL 2017 I get

which is obviously unacceptable. If I compile with TL 2023, I get
! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�\lst@EC�).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.1         \section{Installation sur système
                                               Linux}

which makes me think that your file is coded as Latin-1. Indeed, if I convert your text in a Latin-1 encoded document (StackExchange uses UTF-8) and add
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

the run succeed.

However, you should go away from Latin-1 (and adopt UTF-8). There are still problems with listing and extended character sets, but there are several posts on the site to fix them.
Or switch to minted.

ok thanks I hadn't seen this \red declaration thing. It's the difficulty of getting out of the code of a big project to make a MWE. On the other hand my source file is coded in utf8 and I don't lose the accented characters on my PC, it's strange what happened
